# External party access to smart contract (Block Chain)

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

So if A and B has a smart contract together concerning some service, how does the external party C get access to read/write to this contract?

- would the contract need to be set to this "public" when signing?
- can A or (/and?) B give access to the contract to C after signing?
- any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Basicly all smart contracts on public ledgers are, well, *public*. It depends on which blockchain platform you are deploying the contracts. In general, to access them, you need the following.

1. an *interface*. For instance, in ethereum you need the [application binary interface](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/87). Since the contracts on the chains are stored in a binary format, you need to know how to access their functionality. In most cases an ABI is a JSON description of the available members and functions.
2. some *access* rules. In general, as I said initially, all states are public readable, so if `A` and `B` create a contract with `someService`, `C` will be able to read out the state. If you want to allow `C` write access, you need to explicitly tell either while creating the contract (e.g., by static whitelisting his public key) or you can maintain a dynamic list of accessors which only `A` or `B` can set.

I think this is the most specific answer I can give unless you state the platform or contract language you prefer most.